# about AV for mini laptop

Tags: laptop, anti-virus

is it be clever to install Symantec Endpoint Protection AV on mini laptop ?

is it not to hard for hem ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEP is lightwight if you compare to its predecessors.

We are using it in our business and I can tell you that's it pretty neat and it's working fine. It won't slow down a mini laptop as Dell, Asus and Acer (And...) are selling!

It's using, for me, not more than 11-15mo.

So, no worry at all!

Comment: +1 for answering the question and not turning this into yet another "which is the best virus" thread. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for lightweight antivirus, try [Avira](http://free-av.com); does a nice job without making the app to "bloated"